# Set a fixed cost with an additional cost by item to Woocommerce flat rate

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Is it possible in WooCommerce to have a flat rate shipping for 1 item (in this case 12 $) and for each additional item to add 4$ to it?

So it would be like this

```
1 item  -> $12 in shipping
2 items -> $16
3 items -> $20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without any settings adding `8 + ( [qty] * 4 )` in Cost field:

[image]

This will give you:

- $12 excl. tax for the 1st item ( 8 + ( 1 x 4 ) )
- $16 excl. tax for the 2nd item ( 8 + ( 2 x 4 ) )
- $20 excl. tax for the 3rd item ( 8 + ( 3 x 4 ) )

And so on…

Comment: Thats the ticket! Thanks for the fast and accurate response! Enjoy some Rep!